# How can I convert all URLs in a Google document into links?

Tags: google-drive, links

When I type a URL (such as `http://www.domain.com`) into a Google Drive document, it will automatically be converted into a link that you can click.

But when I copied the contents of a text file containing a bunch of URLs and pasted it into a Google document, none of the URLs were converted into links.

I know that you can select a URL, right-click on it, and select Link, and that will convert it into a link.  But I don't want to have to do that for every URL in the document.

Is there a way to convert all the URLs in a Google document into links in one fell swoop?